# Hibernate query for selecting multiple values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

[image]

The following is my database structure.

I want the following result:

For any retrospective_id entrered by user I want iteration_name,isd,ied,project_name and comments:comment_id,comment_type,comment_text.

What query should I fire?? How to join the tables??Is inner/outer join required??

My code:

**IterationInfo.java**

```
package pojoclasses;

import java.util.Date;

public class IterationInfo
{
    private int iteration_id;
    private int project_id;
    private String iteration_name;
    private Date isd;
    private Date ied;

// getter and setter section

}
```

**Projectinfo.java**

```
package pojoclasses;

public class ProjectInfo 
{
    private int project_id;
    private String project_name;
    // getter and setter section
}
```

**UserInfo.java**

```
package pojoclasses;

public class UserInfo 
{
    private int user_id;
    private String user_name;
    private String email_id;
    private int rally_objectid;
     // getter and setter section
}
```

**RetrospectiveInfo.java**

```
package pojoclasses;

import java.util.Date;

public class RetrospectiveInfo 
{
    private int retrospective_id;
    private Date retrospective_date;
    private int project_id;
    private int iteration_id;
    private int user_id;
    // getter and setter section
}
```

**PageInfo.java**

```
package pojoclasses;

import java.util.Date;

public class PageInfo 
{
    private int comment_id;
    private String comment_text;
    private String comment_type;
    private int user_id;
    private int retrospective_id;
    private Date creation_date;
    private Date modification_date;
    // getter and setter section
}
```

**UserInfo.hbm.cfg**

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <!-- Generated 20 Jan, 2017 2:07:02 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="pojoclasses.UserInfo" table="USERINFO">
    <id name="user_id" type="int">
        <column name="USER_ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="user_name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="USER_NAME" />
    </property>
    <property name="email_id" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="EMAIL_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="rally_objectid" type="int">
        <column name="RALLY_OBJECTID" />
    </property>
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

**RetrospectiveInfo.hbm.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 Jan, 2017 2:06:00 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojoclasses.RetrospectiveInfo" table="RETROSPECTIVEINFO">
    <id name="user_id" type="int">
        <column name="USER_ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="retrospective_id" type="int">
        <column name="RETROSPECTIVE_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="retrospective_date" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="RETROSPECTIVE_DATE" />
    </property>
    <property name="project_id" type="int">
        <column name="PROJECT_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="iteration_id" type="int">
        <column name="ITERATION_ID" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Projectinfo.hbm.cfg**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 Jan, 2017 2:05:23 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojoclasses.ProjectInfo" table="PROJECTINFO">
    <id name="project_id" type="int">
        <column name="PROJECT_ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="project_name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="PROJECT_NAME" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Pageinfo.hbm.cfg**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 Jan, 2017 2:03:56 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojoclasses.PageInfo" table="PAGEDETAILS">
    <id name="user_id" type="int">
        <column name="USER_ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="comment_id" type="int">
        <column name="COMMENT_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="comment_text" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="COMMENT_TEXT" />
    </property>
    <property name="comment_type" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="COMMENT_TYPE" />
    </property>
    <property name="retrospective_id" type="int">
        <column name="RETROSPECTIVE_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="creation_date" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="CREATION_DATE" />
    </property>
    <property name="modification_date" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="MODIFICATION_DATE" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**IterationInfo.hbm.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 Jan, 2017 2:03:23 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojoclasses.IterationInfo" table="ITERATIONINFO">
    <id name="project_id" type="int">
        <column name="PROJECT_ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="iteration_id" type="int">
        <column name="ITERATION_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="iteration_name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="ITERATION_NAME" />
    </property>
    <property name="isd" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="ISD" />
    </property>
    <property name="ied" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="IED" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Main Conteroller class**

```
package packagecontroller;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/json/retrospective")
public class MainControllerClass 
{
@RequestMapping(value="{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<ProjectInfo> getIterationInfoInJSON(@PathVariable int userid)

{
    Configuration con = new Configuration();
    con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session= SF.openSession();
    //Query to be fired..
    session.close();
    SF.close();
    return listiterationinfo;
}
}
```

In oracle sql database the sql queries that give me the desired result:There are 2 queries:

```
SELECT ITERATIONINFO.ITERATION_NAME, ITERATIONINFO.ISD, ITERATIONINFO.IED, PROJECTINFO.PROJECT_NAME
FROM RETROSPECTIVEINFO, PROJECTINFO, ITERATIONINFO
WHERE RETROSPECTIVEINFO.RETROSPECTIVE_ID = 500
AND RETROSPECTIVEINFO.PROJECT_ID = PROJECTINFO.PROJECT_ID
AND RETROSPECTIVEINFO.ITERATION_ID = ITERATIONINFO.ITERATION_ID;

SELECT PAGEDETAILS.COMMENT_ID, PAGEDETAILS.COMMENT_TYPE, PAGEDETAILS.COMMENT_TEXT, USERINFO.USER_NAME, USERINFO.EMAIL_ID
FROM PAGEDETAILS, USERINFO, RETROSPECTIVEINFO
WHERE RETROSPECTIVEINFO.RETROSPECTIVE_ID = 500
AND PAGEDETAILS.RETROSPECTIVE_ID = RETROSPECTIVEINFO.RETROSPECTIVE_ID
AND PAGEDETAILS.USER_ID = USERINFO.USER_ID;
```

Comment: The first thing, you must map your table with object, so we can discuss about how write your query. So, post the objects

Comment: I have created 5 POJO classes for 5 tables in database.I have also created hibernate mapping files and hibernate config file

Comment: Ok, post here. It's important for query how you have created your pojos

Comment: Please, don't post screenshot but text

Comment: I suppose you can write better your pojos using a list of child objects, so the qeury must be more easy

Comment: @JoeTaras I did'nt get you.Can you please tell the hibernate querys for the above 2 sql queries

Comment: Because you have modeled in this way your pojo the SQL query are identical for HQL. Write Query q = session.createQuery("here put the first query"); q.list(); the same thing for the second query

Answer (score 0):

as Joe Taras says in the comment i think you have to rewrite your pojos and mappings better for example i write RetrospectiveInfo class and mapping for you :

```
 package pojoclasses;

public class RetrospectiveInfo 
        {
            private int retrospective_id;
            private Date retrospective_date;
            private ProjectInfo project;
            private IterationInfo iteration;
            private UserInfo user_id;
            // getter and setter section
        }
```

and your mapping will be like this i edit prjoct mapping for you for exmaple  :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 Jan, 2017 2:06:00 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojoclasses.RetrospectiveInfo" table="RETROSPECTIVEINFO">
    <id name="user_id" type="int">
        <column name="USER_ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="retrospective_id" type="int">
        <column name="RETROSPECTIVE_ID" />
    </property>
    <property name="retrospective_date" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="RETROSPECTIVE_DATE" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="project" column="project_id" entityname="pojoclasses.ProjectInfo" />

    <property name="iteration_id" type="int">
        <column name="ITERATION_ID" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and if you rewirte them as i said you can write query like this :

select * from RetrospectiveInfo e 
where e.iteration.iterationName , e.iteration.isd , e.iteration.ied ,
e.iteration.projec.name

i hope this help you.